# Every normal subgroup of $GL_n(K)$ either contains $SL_n(K)$ or is contained in $Z$

Tags: group-theory

In [this page](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/General_linear_group), it is claimed that if $K$ is a field then every normal subgroup of $GL_n(K)$ either contains $SL_n(K)$ or is contained in $Z$ (the center, which is the scalar matrices).

What is the proof? (even one only for $n=2$ would be interesting).

Comment: Are you looking for a proof that $PSL_n(K)$ is simple for $n\ge 2$ (with few exceptions) or for a proof why simplicity implies the statement?

Comment: @j.p.: A proof given this fact is fine. Actually, taking your comment as a hint may be enough.

Comment: Your statement is equivalent to all (nontrivial) normal subgroups of $PGL_n(K)$ containing $PSL_n(K)$. For the exceptions mentioned in my first comment see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projective_linear_group#Finite_fields

Comment: @j.p.: I understand the equivalence. But to understand why your last statement follows from the simplicity of PSL n   (for infinite fields, say), I need to make sure that a nontrivial (normal) subgroup of PGL n   intersects PSL n   nontrivially

Comment: You are right, there is still a gap.

Comment: I think you can close the gap using the fact that a (nontrivial) normal subgroup of a primitive permutation group (PGL acts 2-transitive on the projective geometry) has to be transitive.